# Kaminari on rails4 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I have problem with kaminari gem. I have forum controller. On forum controller show action.View for show action is table with all topics associated with this forum. It looks like this:

```
 class ForumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_forum, only: :show
  def index
    @forums = Forum.all
  end

  def show
   @forum_topics =  @forum.topics.page(params[:page])
  end

  private
  def set_forum
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Forum show view:

```
= paginate @forum_topics
```

At the bottom of the page I see pagination links but when i click to take to the second page i have the same topics like in the first page?
What's wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the pagination links don't use the same name parameter like the one your controller expects:

```
params[:page]
```

Make sure that the urls generated on the pagination links have something like `page=2`

Comment: my url is :http://localhost:3000/forums/1-asdas?page=2 so everything should work fine but it isn't...

Comment: In the url you posted there is a `1-asdas` which is not a valid id. In your set_forum method you call `find` but I guess it raises an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

Comment: It not raises any error because i have to_param method in my forum model:
  def to_param
    [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
  end

Comment: Yes but have you changed the default find method in order search by param and not by id? The ActiveRecord find method searches by id by default.

Comment: when i deleted all to_params method from my app and restore the default it's still not working

Comment: Did You have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you debug inside your controller's show action to see if @forum variable is set?

Comment: How can I do that?
I think that forum variable is set because if forum variable will be not set i couldn't go to the forum show action.
This is my app on github: https://github.com/MatUrbanski/rails_forum_app
Maybe when you see all code you will have any idea.

Comment: Ok, so, post which url redirects to you show page the first time and then which url is generated by kaminari.

Comment: when i visit forum show path i have link :
http://localhost:3000/forums/1-asdas and i have table with all post associated with this forum.
At the bottom i have the pagination links, when i clicked next i have the following url:
http://localhost:3000/forums/1-asdas?page=2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38435/discussion-between-grotori-and-mateusz-urbanski)